# Loopback: Executing a generated method using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, loopbackjs

I want to use a generated method (specifically [__get__accessTokens](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Exposing+models+over+REST#ExposingmodelsoverREST-Hidingendpointsforrelatedmodels)) in JavaScript but I don't know how. I can test that this functionality (getting the tokens of a user) works fine using the REST API Explorer but I can't find any examples of how to access generated methods programmatically and what's their signature. An example of what I need (`Member` extends the default `User` model):

models/member.js

```
 module.exports = function(Member) {
      Member.__get__accessTokens(...)

      // or if I have a specific user (e.g. after executing findById)
      Member.findById(id, function(err, member) {
           member.__get__accessTokens(...)      
      });          
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can user `afterRemote` and `beforeRemote` methods for this.

```
  module.exports  = function(Member) {
      Member.beforeRemote("__your methods__", function(ctx, inst, next){
        var accessToken = ctx.req.accessToken;
        app.models.Member.findById(accessToken.userId, function(err, usr){
          //Process here....
        }
      next();
     }
    }
```

**OR**

You can use current context.
https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Using+current+context

Comment: I'll try to stick to the first solution since using the current context is not recommended.

Answer (score 1):

You can access it from the context:

```
module.exports = function(Product) {  
    var app = require('../../server/server')

    Product.afterRemote('create', function( ctx, modelInstance, next) {
        var accessToken = ctx.req.accessToken

        // get Customer (User) by using the user id in token object
        app.models.Customer.findById(accessToken.userId, function(err, user) {
            modelInstance.createdBy = user.username
            next()
        })
    })
}
```

I use this portion of code to capture the username who create the model through REST API. Full explanation can be found in [here](http://yohanes.gultom.me/loopback-automatic-creation/)